How can deformation have dimension Length if it is not one-dimensional?
Wikipedia says: "In physics and continuum mechanics, deformation is the change in the shape or size of an object. It has dimension of length with SI unit of metre (m)"
I am confused by this, because if I want to give you the entire information in a deformation of a continuous body, I have to give you essentially a continuous function, a whole field which contains the information "point x_1 went to point y_1, point x_2 went to point y_2, ...". But if a deformation has dimension length, then it must be one-dimensional, i.e. a single scalar.
What explains this discrepancy?

Why can't the output of a function have units of length?

First, it's worth nothing the distinction between a scalar and a scalar field. A scalar is one number, that can have dimensions. The speed of a particle is a scalar. A scalar field assigns one number to every point in space. Mathematically, it is a map from $R^3$ to $R$. Temperature is an example of a scalar field. A scalar field can have dimensions, which is clear in this example since temperature has units of Kelvin (or whatever units you are using). In physics, we usually assume a scalar field is as smooth as we need it to be to take derivatives, do Taylor expansions, etc -- so it is often even "better" than "just" continuous.
Second, the deformation of one point in a solid is generally a vector, not a scalar. A point $r$ in the solid can be deformed along the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes in general. Similar to the case of a scalar field, we can also have a vector field. Mathematically, a vector field is a map from $R^3$ to $R^3$. If you are studying continuum mechanics, you have likely come across vector fields before, such as the electric and magnetic fields. Just like the electric and magnetic vector fields, or the temperature scalar field, there is no problem with the deformation field having dimensions. All that this expresses is that if you change your unit of length, you should rescale the values of the components of the deformation field at every point in space to compensate for this unit change.
